# Реализация программы с помощью System.Task

Tags: c#, tpl

Пока реализовываю задачу с помощью `System.Thread`,нужно сделать эту же задачу с помощью `System.Task`

Предполагая, что в некотором каталоге на диске сохранено большое количество файлов с логами (журналами работы) **прокси-сервера**, написать программу вычисляющую статистику потребления трафика сети Интернет. На выходе программа должна создавать три текстовых документа: статистика по пользователям, статистика по доменам, статистика по датам. В качестве статистики использовать общий объем потребленного трафика, соответственно пользователем за все дни, при обращении к домену, в указанный день. При разработке программы считать, что каждый файл должен обрабатываться отдельно параллельно выполняющимся участком кода. После обработки всех файлов, полученные результаты для каждого из них должны суммироваться в общую сводку.

Нужна помощь в составлении алгоритма,код я не прошу.
Просто словесное описание как можно это сделать с помощью `System.Task`

А код я потом напишу и если будут вопросы то скину сюда.

Comment: пример работы с Task - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476910/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-c/476958#476958) после update.

Comment: Опишите, что вы **уже знаете** про `Task` и `async`/`await`. Рассказать вам про то, что это такое и как с ним работать с нуля — это тянет на хорошую, длинную статью, двумя словами тут не обойтись.

Comment: содержимое текстовых файлов такое же как [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473770/)? сколько таких файлов примерно. и сколько строк бывает в файле? если объемы небольшие. то решение - одно, а если логи гигабайтные и user'ов миллионы, то решение должно быть другое.

Comment: Да да такое же.
у меня 10 текстовых в каждом максимум 10 строк.

Мне тоже их надо парсить как с потоками или нет?

Answer (score 2):

> в некотором каталоге на диске сохранено большое количество файлов с логами

Для чтение каталога: Directory.EnumerateFiles -- по мере чтения файлов возвращает их названия и путь.

> файл должен обрабатываться отдельно параллельно выполняющимся участком кода.

Все что связано с обработкой файла надо вынести в отдельный метод, который будет получать путь к файлу, и возвращать результат обработки.

```
TrafficStat Process(string filePath) {
   var stat = new TrafficStat();
   // загрузка и обработка файла
   return stat;
}
```

Этот метод можно вызывать из разных потоков, например, так

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\temp\", "log*.txt")) {
   Task.Run(() => {
      var stat = Process(file);
      // сохраняем stat в файл
   });
}
```

> результаты для каждого из них должны суммироваться в общую сводку.

Т.к. обработка файлов происходит в разных потоках, то надо дождаться завершение потоков, и только после этого можно собрать сводку.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

TrafficStat Process(string path) { 
   // обрабатываем файл, собираем статистику 
}

// запускаем обработку файлов в разных потоках
var ts = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Temp\", "log*.txt")
                  .Select(file => Task.Run(() => Process(file)));

// ждем завершение
Task.WaitAll(ts.ToArray());

// собираем сводку
var result = new int[3];
foreach (var t in ts) {
    if (t.Exception != null) Console.WriteLine(t.Exception);
    else {
        var stat = t.Result;        // TrafficStat
        res[0] += stat.Items.Where(i => i.Key == "User").Sum(i => i.Traffic);
        res[1] += stat.Items.Where(i => i.Key == ...
    }
}
```

---

Для работы `Task` используются потоки из пула потоков. Подробнее [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485283/196972).
Вместо `Task.WaitAll` можно использовать `AttachedToParent`, см. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477434/196972).
Пример парсера лог файла [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485601/196972).