# Запуск потока при каждой итерации цикла

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Суть вопроса опишу практически:

```
while (true)
{
   //Что-то выполняется
   new Thread(DoSmthng).Start(); //Собственно тут должна запускаться функция но в другом потоке.
}

private void DoSmthng()
{
   //Функция не содержит бесконечных циклов
}
```

Насколько мне известно, такой способ не является эффективным в плане потребления ресурсов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать это, сохраняя максимальную производительность.

Comment: А какая у вас задача? Почему вам нужно много потоков? Должна ли функция в одном потоке дожидаться других?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эффективность зависит от того, что происходит в методе DoSmthng.
Если метод завершается относительно быстро, то лучше использовать потоки из пула.
Поставить DoSmthng в очередь на выполнение можно так

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => DoSmthng());
```

Начиная с .NET Framework 4 можно использовать `Task` или `Task<TResult>`

```
Task.Run(() => DoSmthng());
```

Но если поток должен иметь определенный приоритет, или выполняться в STA, или если метод DoSmthng блокирует поток на длительное время, то не следует использовать потоки из пула. Подробнее в [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx) и [тут](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) (Threading in C#, J.Albahari).

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно вы не хотите запускать сразу много потоков, потому что это загрузит систему слишком сильно. Выбор оптимального количества потоков лучше доверить фреймворку.

Если у вас есть много данных, и нужно распараллелить вычисления, делайте так:

```
var results = data.AsParallel().Select(d => DoSmthng(d)).ToList();
```

При этом вычисления будут разбиты на столько потоков, сколько не перегрузит вашу систему.

Это всё, разумеется, для случая, когда ваша задача ограничена скоростью процессора. Если узкое место — чтение данных с диска или из сети, вам стоит перейти к `Task`'ам c async/await, и выполнять операции асинхронно:

```
var tasks = data.Select(d => DoSmthngAsync(d));
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

и реализовать async-вариант `DoSmthng`, в котором ожидание данных не занимает поток, а выполняется на await'е.

Comment: Может лучше ForAll() использовать?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan: Или так, да.