# Вылетает "System.NullReferenceException"

Tags: c#

Задача отсюда [Реализация программы с потоками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473770/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

По шагово отладчиком прошёлся и id,m_threadresult,localstat у меня то 1 и 0 соответственно.
А где откорректировать чтобы не вылетало.

Ведь когда получил список файлов при помощи парсинга,я должен каждый записать в  итоговый отдельный файл.
Но не выходит.

Скрип с местом где исключение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Лабораторная_2
{      
    class countFiles
    {      
        string[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\logfiles", "*.txt");
        public string user 
        { get; set; }
        public string adres
        { get; set; }
        public int trafik
        { get; set; }
        public string data
        { get; set; }


         public countFiles(string userr="", string adress="", int traffic=0)
        {
            user = userr;
            adres = adress;
            trafik = traffic;
        }

      public void parsingfiles(string lline)
        {
            List<countFiles> list = new List<countFiles>(); //здесь будет результат
            for (int i = 1; i < filelist.Length; i++)
            {
                if (filelist[i] == "")
                    continue;
                string[] lineParts = filelist[i].Split(' ');
                list.Add(new countFiles(lineParts[0], lineParts[1], int.Parse(lineParts[2])));
            }
        }

        public void ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    parsingfiles(line);
                }
            }
        }
}

    class StatLog
    {
       public Dictionary<String, UInt64> userstat;
       public Dictionary<String, UInt64> adrestat;
       public Dictionary<int, UInt64> trafikstat;

       public StatLog()//конструктор 
       {
           userstat = new Dictionary<String, UInt64>();
           adrestat = new Dictionary<String, UInt64>();
           trafikstat = new Dictionary<int, UInt64>();
       }

     public StatLog createStat(StatLog info)//
     {
         UInt64 value;
         foreach (var item in info.userstat)
            {              
                userstat[item.Key] = (userstat.TryGetValue(item.Key, out value) ? value : 0) + item.Value;
            }
            foreach (var item in info.adrestat)
            {
                adrestat[item.Key.Trim()] = (adrestat.TryGetValue(item.Key.Trim(), out value) ? value : 0) + item.Value;
            }
            foreach (var item in info.trafikstat)
            {
                trafikstat[item.Key] = (trafikstat.TryGetValue(item.Key, out value) ? value : 0) + item.Value;
            }
            return this;
     }
    }

    class injectfile
    {
        static System.Collections.Generic.List<StatLog> m_threadResult;//результат выполнения потока
        static Queue<String> m_workFiles = new Queue<String>();//очередь файлов с каталога       
        static bool m_iscomplete = false;//флаг завершения ввода
        static readonly object m_locker = new object(); //мютекс для работы с файлами выводимых в очередь

        public void injected(String filelist)//выгрузка файлов в очередь для обработки
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(filelist))
            {
                return;
            }
            lock (m_locker)
            {
                foreach (var x in Directory.EnumerateFiles(filelist))
                {
                    m_workFiles.Enqueue(x);
                }
            }
            m_iscomplete = true;//установить флаг завершения
        }

       public static StatLog  processFile(String file)//обработка файла
        {
            if (!File.Exists(file))///Проверка на наличие файла в каталоге
            {
                return new StatLog();
            }
            StreamReader sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(file);
            String line;
            StatLog sc = new StatLog();//
            countFiles cnt = new countFiles();
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            { 
                cnt.parsingfiles(line);
            }
            return sc;
        }


        static public void threadFunc(int id)
        {
            String value;
            StatLog localStat = m_threadResult[id];
            StatLog sc = new StatLog();
            while (true)
            {
                lock (m_locker)
                {
                    if (m_workFiles.Count < 1)
                    {
                        if (m_iscomplete)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    value = m_workFiles.Dequeue();//получение первого файла из очереди с удалением его из очереди
                }
                var filestat = processFile(value);//обработать файл
                localStat.createStat(filestat);//объеденить статистику
            }
        }       
    }

    class Program
    {      
            static void Main(string[] args)
        {               
           int threadCount = 7;//задаём количество потоков
           string[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\logfiles", "*.txt");     
              System.Collections.Generic.List<StatLog> m_threadResult;//результат выполнения потока
          m_threadResult = new System.Collections.Generic.List<StatLog>(threadCount);
            //и массив потоков
            System.Threading.Thread[] threads = new System.Threading.Thread[threadCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i){
                int id = i;
                m_threadResult.Add(new StatLog());
                threads[i] = new System.Threading.Thread(() => injectfile.threadFunc(id));
                threads[i].Start();
            }
 var statResult = m_threadResult[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < m_threadResult.Count; ++i){
                statResult.createStat(m_threadResult[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Создание файлов статистик");

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\userstat.txt");
            //Пишем в файл
            foreach (var item in statResult.userstat){
                    sw.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            sw.Close();

            StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(@"C:\adrestat.txt");
           foreach (var item in statResult.adrestat){
                    sw1.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            sw1.Close();

            StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(@"D:\trafikstat.txt");
            foreach (var item in statResult.trafikstat)
            {
                sw2.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
            }
            sw2.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Файлы созданы");
            Console.ReadKey();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что у вас в программе есть две переменные m_threadResult. Одна из них - статическое приватное поле в классе injectfile. Вторая - локальная переменная в методе Main программы. Инициализируете вы тоьлко вторую, а используете первую, которая по-прежнему равна null.