# Не создаёт статистику после обработки файлов

Tags: c#

Задание отсюда [Реализация программы с потоками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473770/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Структура файла-лога такая

1. user    adres     trafik  data    User1   Yandex    110     26.06
   User2   Yandex    600     23.07   User3   Google    700     12.08
   User1   Yahoo     800     28.08  User3   Google    100     13.09
   User2   Yandex    120     14.09   User1   Google    140     27.09
   User3   Yahoo     100     23.10   User2   Google    150     16.11
   User1   Yandex    160     17.11   User3   Yahoo     110     24.11
   User2   Google    700     25.11   User1   Yandex    900     18.12

Код исправил исключения не вылетают,создаёт файлы но в них ничего не заносится.

Прошёлся по шагово отладчиком,он всё показывает по нулям.
он увидел 10 файлов директории,сразу переменная filelist присвоилась 10 но дальше в классе статистики пошли сплошные null

Возможно все результаты считывания уходят куда не надо или же я не так произвожу парсинг файлов.
Знаю что ошибка в парсинге файлов и в присвоении но в каком,пытаюсь догадаться.

надеюсь на ваши советы и подсказки.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Лабораторная_2
{      
    class countFiles
    {      
        string[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\logfiles", "*.txt");
        public string user 
        { get; set; }
        public string adres
        { get; set; }
        public int trafik
        { get; set; }
        public string data
        { get; set; }


         public countFiles(string userr="", string adress="", int traffic=0)
        {
            user = userr;
            adres = adress;
            trafik = traffic;
        }

      public void parsingfiles(string lline)
        {
            List<countFiles> list = new List<countFiles>(); //здесь будет результат
            for (int i = 1; i < filelist.Length; i++)
            {
                if (filelist[i] == "")
                    continue;
                string[] lineParts = filelist[i].Split(' ');
                list.Add(new countFiles(lineParts[0], lineParts[1], int.Parse(lineParts[2])));
            }
        }

        public void ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    parsingfiles(line);
                }
            }
        }
}

    class StatLog
    {
       public Dictionary<String, UInt64> userstat;
       public Dictionary<String, UInt64> adrestat;
       public Dictionary<int, UInt64> trafikstat;

       public StatLog()//конструктор 
       {
           userstat = new Dictionary<String, UInt64>();
           adrestat = new Dictionary<String, UInt64>();
           trafikstat = new Dictionary<int, UInt64>();
       }

     public StatLog createStat(StatLog info)//
     {
         UInt64 value;
         foreach (var item in info.userstat)
            {              
                userstat[item.Key] = (userstat.TryGetValue(item.Key, out value) ? value : 0) + item.Value;
            }
            foreach (var item in info.adrestat)
            {
                adrestat[item.Key.Trim()] = (adrestat.TryGetValue(item.Key.Trim(), out value) ? value : 0) + item.Value;
            }
            foreach (var item in info.trafikstat)
            {
                trafikstat[item.Key] = (trafikstat.TryGetValue(item.Key, out value) ? value : 0) + item.Value;
            }
            return this;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Что этот ужас должен делать?

Comment: Есть каталог
там текстовые файлы в которых несколько пользователей,сайты на которых они были и потреблённый трафик.
Программа должна прочесть с каталога эти файлы, обработать и создать отдельных файла статистики по пользователям,сайтам и трафику.

Задание нужно сделать с помощью System.Thread что собственно я  и сделал.

Comment: Вы не могли бы уменьшить пример до минимального, воспроизводящего проблему? Если речь идёт о создании файлов, проверьте, что проблема воспроизводится с одним файлом, и если да, уберите лишний код. То же относится и к получению информации для вывода. Чем меньше ваш код, тем больше вероятность, что кому-то захочется его прочитать и разобраться в проблеме. Мне покамест не хочется.

Comment: Уменьшил до 2 классов где кроется проблема.
класс StatLog отвечает за создание статистики,а в классе countfile я описывал процедуру чтения файла и его парсинга.

Comment: @beginner _"Структура файла-лога"_ -- две строки выводятся как одна? или это тут ошибка форматирования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, есть два файла

log1.txt

```
user    address   traffic  date
User2   Yandex    600      23.07
User1   Yahoo     800      28.08
User2   Yandex    120      14.09
User3   Yahoo     100      23.10
```

log2.txt

```
user    address   traffic  date
User2   Yandex    600      23.07
User1   Yandex    120      14.09
User3   Yahoo     100      23.10
```

---

Для парсинга этих файлов используется метод [ParseFiles](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485601/196972).
Для сбора статистики добавляем следующий класс

```
class TrafficStat {
    public class Item {
        public string Key;
        public int Traffic;
        public DateTime From;
        public DateTime To;
        public string ToCsv(bool header=false) {
            var s = ", ";
            return header 
            ? String.Concat("Key", s, "Traffic", s, "From", s, "To")
            : String.Concat(
                this.Key, s,
                this.Traffic, s,
                this.From.ToString("d.MM"), s,
                this.To.ToString("d.MM"));
        }
    }
    Dictionary<string, Item> tbl = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
    public void Add(string key, Line line) {
        Item itm;
        if (tbl.TryGetValue(key, out itm) == false) {
            itm = new Item { Key = key, From = line.Date, To = line.Date };
            tbl.Add(key, itm);
        }
        itm.From = new DateTime(Math.Min(itm.From.Ticks, line.Date.Ticks));
        itm.To = new DateTime(Math.Max(itm.To.Ticks, line.Date.Ticks));
        itm.Traffic += line.Traffic;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get { return tbl.Values; } }
}
```

---

```
var root = @"C:\Temp\logs\";
var userstat = new TrafficStat();
foreach (var line in ParseFiles(root, "log*.txt", 1)) 
   userstat.Add(line.User, line);

Console.WriteLine(si.ToCsv(true));
foreach (var si in userstat.Items) Console.WriteLine(si.ToCsv());

// записать статистику в файл
File.WriteAllLines(root + "userstat.txt", 
   userstat.Items.Select(si => si.ToCsv()));
```

Результат

```
Key,    Traffic,  From,   To            -- From и To - это мин. и макс. даты
User2,  1320,     23.07,  14.09
User1,  920,      28.08,  14.09
User3,  200,      23.10,  23.10
```

Answer (score 0):

1-ая проблема мне думается,что я не так парсю свои файлы которые выгружаю из каталога.
Но перечитав и посмотрев кучу примеров тут уже не стал уверен в этом.

```
 public void parsingfiles(string lline)
            {
                List<countFiles> list = new List<countFiles>(); //здесь будет результат
                for (int i = 1; i < filelist.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (filelist[i] == "")
                        continue;
                    string[] lineParts = filelist[i].Split(' ');
                    list.Add(new countFiles(lineParts[0], lineParts[1], int.Parse(lineParts[2])));
                }
            }
```

2-ая проблема.Может я не так статистику создаю по файлам.
Создал класс StatLog,словари сделал с занесением статистик но и здесь одни нулевые значения компилятор видит.

```
public StatLog createStat(StatLog info)//
     {
         UInt64 value;
         foreach (var item in info.userstat)
            {              
                userstat[item.Key] = (userstat.TryGetValue(item.Key, out value) ? value : 0) + item.Value;
            }
            foreach (var item in info.adrestat)
            {
                adrestat[item.Key.Trim()] = (adrestat.TryGetValue(item.Key.Trim(), out value) ? value : 0) + item.Value;
            }
            foreach (var item in info.trafikstat)
            {
                trafikstat[item.Key] = (trafikstat.TryGetValue(item.Key, out value) ? value : 0) + item.Value;
            }
            foreach (var item in info.datastat)
            {
                datastat[item.Key] = (datastat.TryGetValue(item.Key, out value) ? value : 0) + item.Value;
            }
            return this;
     }
    }
```