# Парсинг и статистика,недопонимание ситуации с преобразованием,аргументами

Tags: c#

Никак не могу сделать и понять своё задание,поэтому решил по частям выливать сюда.
Так как нужно сделать но нужны подсказки и указания от профессионалов.

Есть некий класс countFiles и в нём есть поля пользователь,адрес,дата,трафик.
Есть конструктор,который всё инициализирует. 
Есть метод parsingfiles,который парсит файлы.

Вопрос: В каком месте я ошибся, файлы пропарсил, результат сохранил в переменную list?

Создаю новый экземпляр класса `countFiles` для обработки следующего файла и вот тут то посыпались ошибки.

```
class countFiles
    {
        public string user
        { get; set; }
        public string adres
        { get; set; }
        public int trafik
        { get; set; }
        public DateTime data
        { get; set; }


        public countFiles(string userr = "", string adress = "", int traffic = 0,DateTime datta=new DateTime())
        {
            user = userr;
            adres = adress;
            trafik = traffic;
            data = datta;
        }

public static countFiles parsingfiles(string lline)
        {
            string[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\logfiles", "*.txt");
            List<countFiles> list = new List<countFiles>(); //здесь будет результат
            DateTime datat;
            int trafic;
            for (int i = 1; i < filelist.Length; i++)
            {
                if (filelist[i] == "")
                    continue;
                string[] lineParts = filelist[i].Split(' ');
                list.Add(new countFiles(lineParts[0], lineParts[1], int.Parse(lineParts[2]),DateTime.Parse(lineParts[3])));

                countFiles ekz = new countFiles(list[user],list[adres],trafic,datat);---Ошибки здесь
                return ekz;
            }
        }
}
```

Ошибки:

1. Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "Лабораторная_2.countFiles.countFiles(string, string, int, System.DateTime)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов

4 поля, всё инициализировано но он ругается что недопустимые.
Почему?

2. Ошибка   1   Для не статического поля, метода или свойства "Лабораторная_2.countFiles.user.get" требуется ссылка на объект.

То есть мне надо и класс и конструктор статическими делать?
А если не хочу?

3. Ошибка   4   Аргумент "1": преобразование типа из "Лабораторная_2.countFiles" в "string" невозможно.

Здесь тупик,так как вопрос тоже интересные строки и лист. Идентично же.
Пропарсил и занёс, пропарсил и занёс,что ему не нравится.

Проблема номер два.

```
static Statistics processFile(String file)
        {
            //если нет файла - то нет и статистики по нему
            if (!File.Exists(file))
            {
                return new Statistics();
            }

            StreamReader sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(file);
            String line;
            Statistics sc = new Statistics();

            //читаем строки
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //парсим
                var ekz = countFiles.parsingfiles(line);                 
                //обновляем статистику по критериям
                UInt64 bytes = 0;
                sc.userstat[ekz.user] = (sc.userstat.TryGetValue(ekz.user, out bytes) ? bytes : 0) + ekz.trafik;
                sc.adrestat[ekz.adres] = (sc.adrestat.TryGetValue(ekz.adres, out bytes) ? bytes : 0) + ekz.trafik;
                sc.trafikstat[ekz.data] = (sc.trafikstat.TryGetValue(ekz.data, out bytes) ? bytes : 0) + ekz.trafik;
            }
            return sc;
        }
```

Ошибка-Оператор "+" не может применяться к операндам типа "ulong" и "int".

Мне статистику надо считать,и у меня там трафик в целом числе,а тут такое?
Это получается надо менять на другой тип что ли?

---

Спасибо за подсказки к классам.

Немного изменил под своё задание,и добавил потоки.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LabWork2
{
public class Line
{
    public string User;
    public string Address;
    public int Traffic;
    public DateTime Date;

    public string ToCsv(bool header = false)
    {
        var s = ", ";
        return header
        ? String.Concat("User", s, "Address", s, "Traffic", s, "Date")
        : String.Concat(
            this.User, s, 
            this.Address, s, 
            this.Traffic, s, 
            this.Date.ToString("d.MM"));
    }


   public static IEnumerable<Line> Parse(string logDir, string pattern, int skip = 0)
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(logDir, pattern))
            foreach (var line in ParseFile(file, 1))
                yield return line;
    }

   public static IEnumerable<Line> ParseFile(string path, int skip = 0)
   {
      return Parse(File.ReadLines(path).Skip(skip));
    }
}


class Stat 
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Key;
        public string Address;
        public int Traffic;
        public DateTime From;
        public DateTime To;

        public string ToCsv(bool header=false)
        {
            var s = ", ";
            return header 
            ? String.Concat("Key", s, "Traffic", s, "From", s, "To")
            : String.Concat(
                this.Key, s,
                this.Traffic, s,
                this.From.ToString("d.MM"), s,
                this.To.ToString("d.MM"));
        }

        public string ToCsv1(bool header = false)
        {
            var s = ", ";
            return header
            ? String.Concat("Adress", s, "Traffic", s)
            : String.Concat(
                this.Address, s,
                this.Traffic, s);
        }

        public string ToCsv2(bool header = false)
        {
            var s = ", ";
            return header
            ? String.Concat( "Traffic", s, "From", s, "To")
            : String.Concat(               
                this.Traffic, s,
                this.From.ToString("d.MM"), s,
                this.To.ToString("d.MM"));
        }

    }

    Dictionary<string, Item> tbl = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

    public void Add(string key, Line line) 
    {
        Item itm;
        if (tbl.TryGetValue(key, out itm) == false)
        {
            itm = new Item { Key = key, From = line.Date, To = line.Date };
            tbl.Add(key, itm);
        }
        itm.From = new DateTime(Math.Min(itm.From.Ticks, line.Date.Ticks));
        itm.To = new DateTime(Math.Max(itm.To.Ticks, line.Date.Ticks));
        itm.Traffic += line.Traffic;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get { return tbl.Values; } }
}
    class Program
    {

        static Queue<String> m_workFiles = new Queue<String>();//файлы на обработку
        static System.Collections.Generic.List<Stat> m_threadResult; //результат выполнения потока
        static bool m_iscomplete = false;//флаг завершения ввода
        static readonly object m_locker = new object();//мьютекс для регулирования доступа к очереди файлов на обработку

        public void processDirectory(String logDir)//извлечь все файлы очередь для обработки
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(logDir))
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (m_locker)//захватить мьютекс
            {
                foreach (var x in Directory.EnumerateFiles(logDir))
                {
                    m_workFiles.Enqueue(x);
                }
            }
            m_iscomplete = true;//установить флаг завершения
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ввод каталога:");
            String logDir = Console.ReadLine();
            Program pr = new Program();
            pr.processDirectory(logDir);


            Line ln = new Line();
            Stat st = new Stat();
            string file;
            var userstat = new Stat();

            Thread[] threads = new Thread[7];
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Line.ParseFile(file,1)));
                threads[i].Name = String.Format("Работает поток {0}",i);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Stat.Add(1,line)));
                threads[i].Name = String.Format("Работает поток {0}", i);
            }

            foreach (var line in ln.ParseFile(logDir, "log*.txt", 1))
            userstat.Add(line.User, line);
            Console.WriteLine(ln.ToCsv(true));
            foreach (var si in userstat.Items) Console.WriteLine(si.ToCsv());                 

            Console.WriteLine("Запись файлов-отчётов");
            File.WriteAllLines(logDir + "userstat.txt",userstat.Items.Select(si => si.ToCsv()));
            File.WriteAllLines(logDir + "adrestat.txt",userstat.Items.Select(si => si.ToCsv1()));
            File.WriteAllLines(logDir + "datastat.txt",userstat.Items.Select(si => si.ToCsv2()));
            Console.WriteLine("Файлы записаны");
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибки

```
threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Line.ParseFile(file,1)));
```

Ошибка  2   Ожидается имя метода.

До этого компилятор ругался что не нужно создавать экземпляр,я напрямую обратился к классу,и пишет что ожидается имя метод.

или нужно делегат создать?

```
threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Stat.Add(1,line)));- Имя "line" отсутствует в текущем контексте
```

Вот здесь я честно сказать забыл,как мне вызвать метод в потоке с параметрами,которые в классе их нужно в мэйне объявлять или ссылку делать?

```
public static IEnumerable<Line> ParseFile(string path, int skip = 0)
{
     return Parse(File.ReadLines(path).Skip(skip));-----    Ни одна из перегрузок метода "Parse" не принимает "1" аргументов,если напишу отдельно каждый всё равно компилятор светит ошибку.
}
```

---

Что я представляю под этими переменными и что я понял из кода, исправленного:
`logDir(root)` - это имя каталога где у меня файлы; 
`pattern` - шаблон файла(его содержимое); 
`skip` - количество элементов в которых пройдётся одноимённый метод `Skip`.

```
public static IEnumerable<Line> Parse(string logDir, string pattern, int skip = 0)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(logDir, pattern))
        foreach (var line in ParseFile(logDir,file, 1))
            yield return line;
}

public static IEnumerable<Line> ParseFile(string path,string text, int skip = 0)
{
    return Parse(File.ReadLines(path).Skip(skip),File.ReadAllText(text).Skip(skip),File.ReadAllText(text.ToString()).Skip(skip));
}
```

В этой строке `return Parse(File.ReadLines(path).Skip(skip),File.ReadAllText(text).Skip(skip),File.ReadAllText(text.ToString()).Skip(skip));`

Куча ошибок:

- Ошибка    1   Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "System.IO.File.ReadAllText(string)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов
- Ошибка    2   Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "LabWork2.Line.Parse(string, string, int)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов
- Ошибка    3   Аргумент "1": преобразование типа из "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" в "string" невозможно
- Ошибка    4   Аргумент "2": преобразование типа из "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" в "string" невозможно
- Ошибка    5   Аргумент "3": преобразование типа из "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" в "int" невозможно

Метод `Parse()` вызываем с 3-мя аргументами.
То есть считываю путь и шаблон файла и количество элементов.

Если 1-ый я понял,то со 2-ым и 3-ем недопонимание.

С помощью `ReadAllText` я уже читаю имя файла или его содержимое(2-ой аргумент).

По поводу 3-его раз уж аргумент целое число то или ToString или ToInt применять?

По поводу преобразований я думаю что после ошибок с аргументами может и уйдут ошибки.

Comment: Опишите решаемую задачу, тогда я смогу привести вариант как исправить. Пока реализация метода **processFile** выглядит весьма странно и не понятно какого результата вы от нее ожидаете

Comment: пожалуйста, вносите изменения в вопрос, а не оформляйте их как отдельные ответы.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде много ошибок, но попробуем разобрать перечисленные вами по порядку.

> ОШибка- 1)Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для
>   "Лабораторная_2.countFiles.countFiles(string, string, int,
>   System.DateTime)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов
>
> 4 поля,всё инициализировано но он ругается что недопустимые. Почему?

Эта ошибка возникает потому, что вы передаете не верные аргументы в конструктор,смотрим подробнее:

countFiles ekz = new countFiles(**list[user]**, **list[adres]**,trafic,datat);

Выделенные аргументы **не являются строками, которые ожидает конструктор, а являются элементами list**, который у вас определен как `List<countFiles> list` из чего следует, что **list состоит из объектов countFiles**

> 2)Ошибка 1 Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства
>   "Лабораторная_2.countFiles.user.get" требуется ссылка на объект То
>   есть мне надо и класс и конструктор статическими делать? А если не
>   хочу.

Эта ошибка вызвана обращением к не статическим полям класса из статического метода (см. выделение):

countFiles ekz = new countFiles(list[**user**],list[**adres**],trafic,datat);

В коде статического метода можно обращаться только к статическим членам класса.
В данном месте вашего кода я, честно говоря, вообще не понял какой результат вы ожидали увидеть, думаю стоит добавить в вопрос описание решаемой задачи, тогда вам смогут предложить вариант исправления.

> 3)Ошибка 4 Аргумент "1": преобразование типа из
>   "Лабораторная_2.countFiles" в "string" невозможно Здесь тупик,так как
>   вопрос тоже интересные строки и лист.идентично же. Пропарсил и
>   занёс,пропарсил и занёс,что ему не нравится

см. ответ к первой ошибке.

> Ошибка-Оператор "+" не может применяться к операндам типа "ulong" и
>   "int"
>
> Мне статистику надо считать,и у меня там трафик в целом числе,а тут
>   такое? это получается надо менять на другой тип что ли?

Менять тип поля в классе не обязательно, достаточно привести все слагаемые выражения к `ulong`. Однако если в полях класса вы храните только положительные числа, возможно это имеет смысл.

**Update**
Попробуйте исправить строку:

countFiles ekz = new countFiles(list[user],list[adres],trafic,datat);---Ошибки здесь

таким образом:

```
countFiles ekz = new countFiles(list[i].user,list[i].adres,trafic,datat);
```

Компилироваться будет, но над архитектурой еще работать и работать.

Ну и по поводу целых чисел. .NET поддерживает 2 варианта целых чисел, со знаком и без знака. Арифметические операции между ними без явного приведения запрещены, т.к. нет взаимно однозначного отображения беззнаковых целых в знаковые и наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

Если надо распарсить следующий текстовый файл

```
user    address   traffic  date
User2   Yandex    600      23.07
User1   Yahoo     800      28.08
User2   Yandex    120      14.09
User3   Yahoo     100      23.10
User1   Yandex    160      17.11
User2   Google    700      25.11
```

То пишем так

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Line {
    public string User;
    public string Address;
    public int Traffic;
    public DateTime Date;
    public string ToCsv(bool header = false) {
        var s = ", ";
        return header
        ? String.Concat("User", s, "Address", s, "Traffic", s, "Date")
        : String.Concat(
            this.User, s, 
            this.Address, s, 
            this.Traffic, s, 
            this.Date.ToString("d.MM"));
    }
}
static IEnumerable<Line> Parse(IEnumerable<string> lines) {
    foreach (var line in lines) {
        var arr = Regex.Split(line.Trim(), @"\s+");
        yield return new Line {
            User = arr[0],
            Address = arr[1],
            Traffic = int.Parse(arr[2]),
            Date = DateTime.ParseExact(arr[3], "d.MM", null)
        };
    }
}
static IEnumerable<Line> ParseFile(string path, int skip=0) {
    return Parse(File.ReadLines(path).Skip(skip));
}
```

---

```
var root = @"C:\Temp\";
foreach (var line in ParseFile(root + "log1.txt", 1))
   Console.WriteLine(line.ToCsv());
```

Результат

```
User2, Yandex, 600, 23.07
User1, Yahoo, 800, 28.08
User2, Yandex, 120, 14.09
User3, Yahoo, 100, 23.10
User1, Yandex, 160, 17.11
User2, Google, 700, 25.11
```

---

Если надо парсить несколько файлов, например, log1.txt, log2.txt и т.д., то пишем так

```
static IEnumerable<Line> ParseFiles(string root, string pattern, int skip=0) {
  foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, pattern))
     foreach (var line in ParseFile(file, 1))
        yield return line;
}
```

---

```
var root = @"C:\Temp\logs\";
foreach (var line in ParseFiles(root, "log*.txt", 1))
  Console.WriteLine(line.ToCsv());
```

---

**UPDATE**

Для сбора статистики можно использовать класс [TrafficStat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485650/196972).

Answer (score 0):

Для параллельной обработки элементов коллекции можно использовать метод AsParallel вместе с ForAll

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;

var cq = new ConcurrentQueue<TrafficStat>();
var root = @"C:\Temp\logs\";
// параллельно ...
Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, "log*.txt").AsParallel().ForAll(file => {
    Console.WriteLine("@" + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId + "\t" + file);
    var userstat = new TrafficStat();
    // собрать статистику из файла
    foreach (var line in ParseFile(file, 1))
        userstat.Add(line.User, line);
    // сохранить статистику для дальнейшего агрегирования
    cq.Enqueue(userstat);
});
Console.WriteLine(cq.Count);
```

---

Тоже самое на основе Task можно сделать так

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var cq = new ConcurrentQueue<TrafficStat>();
var root = @"C:\Temp\logs\";
// параллельно ...
var ts = Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, "log*.txt").Select(file => {
    return Task.Run(() => {
        Console.WriteLine("@" + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId + " " + file);
        var userstat = new TrafficStat();
        // собрать статистику из файла
        foreach (var line in ParseFile(file, 1))
            userstat.Add(line.User, line);
        // сохранить статистику для дальнейшего агрегирования
        cq.Enqueue(userstat);
    });
});
Task.WaitAll(ts.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(cq.Count);
```